# Connectivity between switches using SFP+

Tags: networking, switch, infrastructure, sfp

My office infrastructure is currently configured with HP Procurve switches. They are interconnected with 10Gbps fibre. All the SFP+ Ports are in use on all the switches.

I am looking at buying a new switch that has only SFP+ ports to use as our core switch and in which all our switches will plug in to. I've read that the SFP+ Protocol is standardized.

Does this mean I could buy a Cisco core switch and have the HP switches terminate into without any sort of issues? I have people tell me that trying to mix manufacturers in this sort of configuration is a bad idea and that things will probably not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I could buy a Cisco core switch and have the HP
>   switches terminate into without any sort of issues?

I've never heard of any issues with this, certainly I'd suggest you use Cisco SFP+'s in Cisco devices and HPE SFP+'s for HPE devices but otherwise as long as you get the cabling right (try to stick to OM4 LC-LC 50/125u fibres) then you're going to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could buy a Cisco core switch and have the HP switches terminate into without any issue. If you plug the compatible SFP+ modules in Cisco switch, and use the right SFP+transceivers on HPE switch, and then choose the right cable type, say multi-mode fiber, you can make it.

Answer (score -2):

It is not advisable for you to purchase the Cisco switch in your existing network. Because switches from Cisco and HP are designed to have their unique function even though they can both support 10G Ethernet.